# Qt creator opens fours windows when I press "develop"

Tags: qt, ubuntu, qt-creator

I have Qt Creator 2.7.1 running on Ubuntu 13.10 32-bit. When I push the reference "develop" or "examples" or "getting started" at the same time opened four windows (see. images). I can't close those windows. How can I fix that problem?
[image: Screenshot]
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Does it also happen when not running Unity?

Comment: I don't know about Unity. I just start that application (Qt creator).

Comment: Unity is your desktop environment. Please check if you get the same with Gnome, KWin or other desktop environments. You can probably choose another one in your login screen.

Comment: I have tried to launch Qt creator in the Gnome Classic, LXDE, Razor but the problem doesn't dissapear.